# indexPath is nil after didSelectRow in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue

I want to pass the selected row to the next VC.
But it is always nil, no matter which row was clicked.
I'm happy for any hints.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetails", sender: self)
        
        
    }
    
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goTo Details" {
            if let indexPath = collectionTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
                destinationVC.IdentifierAlbum = dataArray[indexPath.row].album
                destinationVC.IdentifierArtist = dataArray[indexPath.row].artist
                destinationVC.IdentifierRow = indexPath.row
                print (indexPath.row)
            }
```

Comment: When you created the segue in Storyboard, I guess you did from the `UITableViewCell` to `DetailsViewController`. Remove it, and do it from the `ViewController` where is the UITableView to `DetailsViewController`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your thought, but the segue is not from the cell. It's from the first VC to the second VC.

Comment: Side note, the segue identifier is not the same (there is an extra space). Do you even get to `destinationVC.IdentifierRow = indexPath.row`? I know that segue can only been down between VC, but on creation, if you start the dragging from the cell, it will be triggered BEFORE your delegate methods gets called, resulting in that issue.

Comment: Damn... will create a constants file now.

Comment: FYI, there are tools that can parse your Storyboards and generate constants from them (including segue identifiers, vc identifiers, etc), like SwiftGen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `self` you could pass the index path

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetails", sender: indexPath) 
}
```

and get it in `prepare(for`, by the way the identifier doesn't match the identifier of `performSegue`, check it also in the storyboard

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToDetails",
       let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath { ...
```

But if the segue is connected from table view cell to the destination controller rather than from the view controller you can delete `didSelectRow` and the `sender` parameter contains the instance of the selected cell

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToDetails", 
       let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
       let indexPath = collectionTableView.indexPath(for: cell) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your **IndexPath** as your sender

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goTo Details", sender: indexPath)

}
```

then on your **prepare(for segue:)** get the index path as follows

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goTo Details",
       let destinationVC = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController,
       let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {

        //Whatever you do with indexPath

    }
}
```